# Flask is running in different port

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I am running a simple flask app like following in pycharm

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5005)
```

When I run it , it always run in 5000 port ,this the message I am seeing in pycharm console

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But rather than using pycharm if I run the project from terminal like following

`python3 app.py`

It runs on 5005 port .

How can solve this ?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` only runs when you call the function by name in the terminal, and not when you run it with `flask run`. Try removing this condition.

Comment: Did you make sure you are running this in PyCharm as `__main__`?

Comment: @Stanowczo yes  I made that sure

Comment: @Ardweaden `Warning: Silently ignoring app.run() because the application is run from the flask command line executable.  Consider putting app.run() behind an if __name__ == "__main__" guard to silence this warning.
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5005)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 ` Thats what I got.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your project is a Flask Project.Pycharm will take over some settings
[image]

you can close it.then, your settings for flask app will work
[image]